# Common build targets and assembly.cs file updates

Tags: c#, configuration, msbuild

I'm currently working somewhere that have some standard settings that are applied to solutions but I'm having to repeatedly apply the settings over and over again. I wondered what the best solution would be to automate some of this.

For eg:

1. Assembly.cs has to be updated each time to include [assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("0.0.0.0")]
2. projects have to have this added manually

I'm thinking that I could create a custom msbuild file that could do this and then that would be one place to manually add the settings for the projects.

It is a bit tedious if there are multiple projects that have to have their csproj files edited and some msbuild settings added each time.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Create your own project template with File > Export Template.

Comment: Thats awesome, I didn't even think about doing that! You should have added that as an answer as its just what I need.

Answer (score 4):

A way to do this is to use a custom task provided by open source project http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/.

There is a task called AssemblyInfoFile which writes an assemblyFile as specified.

You can create a .proj file which imports this task:

`<Import Project="YourPathToCommunity.targets\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />`

and then executes it before compiling.

`<Target Name="BeforeCompile">
        <AssemblyInfo OutputFile="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"
            AssemblyVersion="$(AssemblyVersion)"
            AssemblyFileVersion="$(AssemblyVersion)"/>
  </Target>`

Then, for every project file that you want this behaviour to be applied, just import the .proj file defined in the previous step:

`<Import Project="PathToYourProj\myDefinedProj.proj" />`

Comment: Thats great. A mixture of your answer and the one from Hans is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, when those projects need to be updated? Do you use any custom build process?

If you have do to this ALL the time, not only when you need a build ready to be a version, then you should do what @arthur-rizzo recommended, and I add that you should name your file with a .targets extension, since it adds a generic target to complement a project, not a standalone project. Besides, make sure you import this file after any other import that would possibly override the BeforeCompile target. A more secure way to do this IMHO is to give your target some other name like "UpdateAssemblyFile" and add the attribute BeforeTargets="Compile", so you make sure your target will not be overriden and it makes more clear for other developers what's the intend of the target.

So your file would be something like:

```
<Import Project="YourPathToCommunity.targets\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
<Target Name="UpdateAssemblyFile" BeforeTargets="Compile">
    <AssemblyInfo OutputFile="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"
        AssemblyVersion="$(AssemblyVersion)"
        AssemblyFileVersion="$(AssemblyVersion)"/>
</Target>
```

And you will import it in the ALL the projects you want this custom behaviour like this: `<Import Project="TheFileYouCreated.targets" />`

Don't forget to add this file to the source control you use.

Credits for @arthur-rizzo for the original answer and adding a link to the custom tasks library.